# Have two entity in Grails with one to many relationship

Tags: grails, one-to-many

I have two entity in Grails with one to many relationship Location and LocationImage

```
class Location {

  Long phone;
  String url;

  static hasMany = [locationImage: LocationImage]

  static constraints = {
    phone(blank: true, nullable: true)
    url(blank: true, nullable: true)
    locationImage(nullable: true)
  }
}




 class LocationImage {

    String description
    String path

    static belongsTo = [location:Location]


   static constraints = {
    description(blank:true,nullable:true)       
}
```

}

How can I find path attribute in locationImage table by forien key location Id?

Comment: Here for a single location there may be multiple path, do you want all path for given location?

Comment: yes I want to get all by forien key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved it ,that's what I need

```
 def getLocationImage(String locationName){
   def location = Location.findByName(locationName)
   def locationImage = LocationImage.createCriteria().list{
      and {
      eq('location',location)
   }
   }
    return locationImage.path
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all path as :

```
def locationImages = location.locationImage
def paths = locationImages*.path
```

Comment: This works but it's very inefficient. This probably wins for shortest code, but that's a terrible selection criterion. You load all of the collection elements to extract one property, and if there are a lot of items, and/or there are many columns, then you're loading a lot of unnecessary data and throwing it away.

Comment: ok Thanks but if  got location by url like that                        def getLocationByUrl(String locationUrl){
  def location = Location.findByUrl(locationUrl)
  return location
 }                                                                            now I want to get the path of image from locationImage table by forien key,How can I do that?